# What's wrong with my islower and isupper?

Tags: c++

Holle ,I typed a c++ program follow my C++ PrimerPlus 6 and When I run it the result is incredible for me,Could you please tell me What's wrong with it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
      using namespace std;

      cout << "Enter your message and type @ to an end." << endl;
      char ch;

      int digit;
      int alpha;
      int lower;
      int supper;
      int punct;

      cin.get(ch);

      while ( ch != '@' )
      {
              if ( isdigit(ch) )
                      digit++;
              else if ( isalpha(ch) )
                      alpha++;
              else if ( islower(ch) )
                      lower++;
              else if ( isupper(ch) )
                      supper++;
              else
                      punct++;
              cin.get(ch);
      }
      cout << "Digits: " << digit << endl << "Alpha: " << alpha
             << endl << "Lower: " << lower << endl << "Supper: "
             << supper << endl << "Puncts: " << punct << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

And it showed those:
[image]

Comment: You should count `lower` and `supper` inside `if islower(ch)` block.

Comment: I suggest:  initialize your variables (that's your problem); describe in text here what you expected, and what it did, on a small example; and there's no need to curse at us unless we did something to deserve it. :)

Comment: Please don't include potentially offensive language in your questions, even if it is part of the code

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. My compiler warns me that those variables are used uninitialized.

Comment: Oh ,sorry ,it is a result of listening too many rap musics,,,,Eminem  2Pac,,,@JacobGray

Comment: No any warnings,only nonpreditable results@chris

Comment: So sorry,never meaning that ,just a result of listening too many rap music@TopologicalSort

Comment: isupper... sounds like dinner at Steve Job's house.

Comment: @user4581301 same thought here..esp. when he name the counter as supper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter the character `ch` is lower or upper, it will be counted as alphabet and it will be counted in `alpha`

```
 if ( isdigit(ch) )
          digit++;
 else if ( isalpha(ch) )
          alpha++;  // All alphabet will count to here
 else if ( islower(ch) )
          lower++;  // this won't run
 else if ( isupper(ch) )
          supper++; // this won't run
 else
          punct++;
 cin.get(ch);
```

As you did not initialize both `lower` and `supper`, their value is random and thus you will see some nonpreditable results